# How could I get the selected item from multiple dynamically added Select2 dropdowns?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I am working on a C# Asp.Net web application, and I am trying to add the ability to dynamically add some select2 dropdowns on our project creation form.

So far, I've been able to add a single dropdown with a partial view, and get the results from it back to the controller using the viewmodel. I can also add additional dropdowns using jquery, and those dropdowns search correctly. But I'm having trouble getting the results from those additional inputs into the controller.

Methods I have tried:

- Appending the partial ... tag instead of the select...
- Changing the select `asp-for="TeamMembers`... to select `asp-for="TeamMembers[0]... [1][2]`, ect.
- Adding the `@if`... statement from the controller to the var html string
- Escaping the @ in the `@if` ... line

Partial View that successfuly works once

```
@model Waypoints.ViewModels.ProjectsCreateViewModel

<h5>Add Team Members</h5>
<div class="form-group" id="teamMembersAddDiv">
    <select asp-for="TeamMembers" class="project-team-members-enabled form-control">
        @if (null != Model && null != Model.TeamMembers)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.TeamMembers.OrderBy(i => i))
            {
                <option selected="selected">@item</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" class="btnAdd" value="+" />
```

Javascript that adds a select2 dropdown that doesn't add to the viewmodel

```
        function addRow() {
            var html = '<select asp-for="TeamMembers" class="project-team-members-enabled form-control">'
                +'@if (null != Model && null != Model.TeamMembers){foreach (var item in Model.TeamMembers.OrderBy(i => i)){<option selected="selected">@item</option>}}'
                + '</select>'
            $(html).appendTo($("#teamMembersAddDiv"))

            $('.project-team-members-enabled').select2({
            tokenSeparators: [","],
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            ajax: {
                delay: 150,
                url: '@Url.Action("TypeaheadSearch", "Profiles")',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        pageSize: 10,
                        pageNum: params.page || 1,
                        searchTerm: params.term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    params.page = params.page || 1;
                    return {
                        results: data.results,
                        pagination: {
                            more: (params.page * 10) <= data.total
                        }
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            createTag: function (params) {
                var term = $.trim(params.term).replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
                    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                        txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                });

                if (term === '') {
                    return null;
                }
                if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+( [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$/g.test(term)) {
                    return null;
                }

                return {
                    id: term,
                    text: term

                }
            }
        });
        };
```

Viewmodel TeamMembers

```
TeamMembers = new List<string>();
...
public IList<string> TeamMembers { get; set; }
```

I would assume that there is some way to get the selected text item from a dropdown, and save it to the viewmodel before the viewmodel is posted to the controller. But I haven't been able to find it so far, and I'm hoping someone else might know.

Comment: Instead of have multiple `<select>`'s for the TeamMembers field, have you tried making 1 `<select>` and making it a [select2 multi-select](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox)? You might then have better luck binding it to your ViewModel which is a list and not separate fields

Comment: Yes, that was the inital plan and it worked. But because we also have a Tag entry field that's another multiselect right next to it, it was a bit visually confusing. So the next plan was individual inputs for each team member.